# Google-Sheet - query multiple unknown sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Context: I need to develop a Google Sheet to manage yearly cost and revenues from the Charity where I volunteer. This file will be updated from volunteers, so I need to develop a structure which they can use with easiness.

My idea:

- have a front sheet with a summary from activities and charts
- let volunteers duplicate a template event cost and revenue and add their c&r

Result would have as much sheets as many Events and Charity or Fundraising events/campaign.

But, since the number of sheets is unknown till the end of the year, how can I have a summary sheet?

**E.G. How can I sum all costs and all rev? Can I query to search in **all existing sheets** the cell that follows an exact string (e.g. Total Rev)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can write an [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) - a Google Script service based on Javascript

It is relatively simple to learn and use and it will allow you to loop dynamically through all the sheets without knowing in advance how many there will be.

The following sample script iterates through all sheets minus the master sheet of the spreadsheet to which it is bound and sums the values of the cells "A10" (if this is the cell where you have your costs) together. Finally it sets the value of the sum into the cell "A10" fo the master sheet.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets=ss.getSheets();
  var sum=0;
  for (var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++){
    if(sheets[i].getName()!="Master"){
      var value=sheets[i].getRange("A10").getValue();
      sum=sum+value;
    }
  }
  ss.getSheetByName("Master").getRange("A10").setValue(sum);
}
```

If you take some time to get familiar with Apps Script, you will be able to easily adapt the sample above to your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly. I've triggered it to actionate each time an edit is made, so it's always up to date. As I don't know scripts language, con you just help me to understand how to add additional actions?

Comment: What do you mean by additional actions?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. As well as costs I need to collect other data from specific cells from the remaining sheets, but I'm not familiar with this language. So my question is: which is the best way to add new instructions? Should I repeat from `for` to `getRange("A10").setValue(sum);` with the new parameters?

Comment: If you want to add data from other cells you basically do the same procedure, just replace "A10" through the correspondent cell(s) containing your data of interest. However, if you want to get data from a range that is bigger than one cell (e.g. `getRange("A10:C10")` ), you need to replace `getValue` through `getValues` and `setValue` through `setValues`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that the volunteers don't fill out anything on the sheet at all.

You can collect all you need from the volunteers via a google Form.  That form will dump all the data into a single tab in google sheets from which it will be easy to analyze and summarize the data that you want to see and share with the whole team.

Comment: yes, that could be a smart solution, but I need the designed people to be able to view and change / add data. I know I could allow them to access the file as well, but it wouldn't be easy to manage single event cost and rev entries.